# Is it possible to include image in email as attachment using a cid and web server URL?

Tags: html, image, src, outlook-2010

I am working on an email signature to be sent from Outlook and Outlook web client that will be applied to all individuals in a company using adolsign (a third party tool that generates an email signature based on AD information and an html template).

It needs to contain a logo.

Based on my research, images linked directly from a web server as below cause two problems. 1. They are often blocked by web clients for security reasons and 2. they are unavailable when the user has downloaded an email and opens it offline.

```
<img src="http://www.myurl.com/myimage" width="142" height="30" >
```

Embedding the image using SVG or a 64 bit encoded data tag doesn't work in Outlook, so that is not an option.

I believe that using the cid tag to create and reference a hidden attachment is my best option for this particular client, but I'm struggling to get this to work using a url. Using a network file path is not a great option as it won't resolve for users sending emails from the web client. I'd like to use something like this but it doesn't render when I open it in Outlook:

```
<img src="cid:http://www.myurl.com/myimage" width="142" height="30" >
```

My hope is to get Outlook to create and reference an attachment in the email that is downloaded from the url when the email is sent.

How do I accomplish this? Is it possible? Please let me know if some of the assumptions I am making are incorrect.

Comment: this question may be more appropriately asked on ServerFault

Comment: Sure. I will ask over there. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @AnthonyShaw This is a programming question, not a question for [sf].

Comment: @MichaelHampton he's trying to get Outlook to create and reference the image attachment while utilizing a third-party system. Doesn't seem like there is much programming involved outside of adding the correct html to his email signature

Comment: I think he'd get a better answer from someone on Server Fault who is more familiar with Outlook and it's CID referencing, my bad